# How to update/blit plot in same figure? (Matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib, plot, real-time, figure, blit

I am trying to plot data to the same figure every 10 seconds, but after every iteration a new figure gets displayed.

**How can I update the plot in the same figure?**

**Is this the most efficient way to do so?** I need to handle far more data in the future and need to update the plots in the fastest possible way.

Here is the code:

`plotToFigure()` is receiving 8.000.000 numerical values every 10 sec from `data_handler`, so `np_data_list` is an array containing these 8.000.000 values. It then plots the data to a figure (starting from 1000th value every 1000th value):

```
 def plotToFigure(self):
    #
    np_data_list = self.data_handler.np_data_list[0]
    x_axis = np.arange(len(np_data_list))
    #
    self.line, = self.axis.plot(x_axis[1000::1000], np_data_list[1000::1000])
    #
    self.canvas = self.figure.canvas
    self.canvas.draw()  # Do I need this?
    self.canvas.flush_events()
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axis.bbox)
    #
    self.figure.show()
    #plt.show() # What is the difference?
    #
```

`updateFigure()` is receiving again 8.000.000 and should update the figure with the new values (the second `updateFigure()` function is basically doing the same as the first one, but also not updating the current figure);

If `self.figure.show()` is not in the code, only the figure from `plotToFigure()` will get displayed and the figure will not get updated:

```
def updateFigure(self):
    #
    np_data_list = self.data_handler.np_data_list[0]
    self.line.set_ydata(np_data_list[1000::1000])
    #
    self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)  # restore background
    self.axis.draw_artist(self.line)  # redraw just the line
    self.figure.canvas.blit(self.axis.bbox)  # fill in the axes rectangle
    #
    self.figure.show()
    #
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axis.bbox)
    #

'''
def updateFigure(self):
    #
    np_data_list = self.data_handler.np_data_list[0]
    self.line.set_ydata(np_data_list[1000::1000])
    #
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
    #
    #self.canvas.draw() ??
    #self.canvas.flush_events() ??
    #
'''
```

This is an example where data_handler is receiving 8.000.000 numerical values, every 10 seconds, three times in a row and passes it to plotter:

```
# ------ MAIN PROGRAM ------ #
...
...
#
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data_plotter = class_DataPlotter.DataPlotter(data_handler, fig, ax)
#
data_handler.getDataFromDataAcquisitionObject()
data_plotter.plotToFigure()
#
data_handler.getDataFromDataAcquisitionObject()
data_plotter.updateFigure()
#
data_handler.getDataFromDataAcquisitionObject()
data_plotter.updateFigure()
#
...
...
#
```

This is the output I get in Pycharm
[image: 1]